# Show & hide html element based on selected text using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to set attribute name & show select option if the selected text is not "Super Admin" and unset the attribute name & hide the select option if the selected text is "Super Admin".

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <select id="role_user" name="role" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Select role user</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
     <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The element that I want to show & hide:

```
<div class="form-group" id="company" style="display: none">
     <label>Company</label>
     <select id="company_i" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Company</option>
         @foreach ($company as $cp)
         <option value="{{ $cp->id }}">{{ $cp->name }}</option>
         @endforeach
     </select>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#role_user').change(function() {
                    if ($('#role_user option:selected').text() != "Super Admin") {
                        $('#company').show();
                        $('#company_i').attr('name', 'company_id');
                    } else if ($('#role_user option:selected').text() == "Super Admin") {
                        $('#company').hide();
                        $('#company_i').removeAttr("name");
                    }
                })
            });
```

I have tried it using the code above, but only the set & remove name attribute are working. The show & hide not working.

Comment: Odd. code seems ok i think. Is anything being logged in your `console.log` ? is it possible you maybe have another `id="company"` field on your site ? (just a wild stab in the dark really)

Comment: You could try `$('#company').css('display', 'block');` instead of `show()` and `$('#company').css('display', 'none');` instead of `hide()`. perhaps that makes a difference

Comment: Thanks!! @Raxi, I have 2 element with id=company

Comment: i am a god amongst men

Comment: @Catto id needs to be unique - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @mk21 Thanks for your comment, yeah I know. I just don't realize it because I'm using blade template engine & each section is included from different files (I'm only focused in 1 files for this one, which is my fault)

Comment: Your code is already working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#role_user').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "Super Admin") {
            $('#company').show();
            $('#company_i').attr('name', 'company_id');
        } else {
            $('#company').hide();
            $('#company_i').removeAttr("name");
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="role_user" name="role" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select role user</option>
        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
        <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="company" style="display: none">
    <label>Company</label>
    <select id="company_i" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Company</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, bro @Nikhil Parmar, I'd to pray for you for your good work